# Не приходят автоматически регистрируемые события в FirebaseAnalytics

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase, firebase-android, firebaseanalytics

После обновления приложения, перестали приходить данные в FirebaseAnalytics, те которые **Автоматически регистрируемые события** https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9234069?hl=ru Библиотеки связанные с Firebase остались те же, файл и проект тоже(в студии надпись Connected), и подключение такое же, но данные перестали приходить(кастомных ивентов, не было). Такое ощущение что, что-то мешает отправке данных из приложения в Firebase. Попытался подебажить строку `mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)`
Чтобы посмотреть что внутри **mFirebaseAnalytics**, вдруг увижу где-то null или еще что, но там столько всего что не понятно куда смотреть. Есть ли способы программно узнать идет ли отправка данных в Firebase? Или может кто-то сталкивался с подобным, что еще это может быть, подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать!?

Answer (score 1):

Ты не забыл вставить эту строку ?

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

В метод onCreate() в классе Application

Comment: Этой строки и раньше не было в приложении и все работало, и я не вижу ее здесь https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=android, потому нет не добавлял

Comment: Хм, действительно это не обязательно добавлять, эта функция должна по дефолту вызываться в Firebase SDK. Как вариант могу посоветовать проверить правильность размещения файла googe-services.json + можно продебажить события, которые прила шлёт в Firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview

Comment: Действительно странно, но мне помогло. Спасибо